# How to attach files during user registration process in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a registration web app using Laravel 8, I'm quite new in Laravel. It can be accessed through this link: http://bidvest.inboundinnovative.com/
I would like users to attach files during registration (I will have 3 file upload fields in my form).
Please help me come up with logic code for validating and uploading the files both in a directory and in mySQL database. I have checked for solutions online but none of them has worked. Please help me, Thanks.

Below is a section of the form with file uploading fields in blade template:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<label for="kra_pindoc">Attach KRA Document</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="kra_pindoc" name="kra_pindoc">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<label for="id_carddoc">Attach ID Document</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="id_carddoc" name="id_carddoc">
</div>
</div>
```

My RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
   
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/success';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make(
            $data,
            [
            'surname'               => 'required|string|max:255',
            'middle_name'           => 'required|string|max:255',
            'first_name'            => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
            'username'              => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users|alpha_dash',
            ]
        );
    }

   
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'surname'               => $data['surname'],
            'middle_name'           => $data['middle_name'],
            'first_name'            => $data['first_name'],
            'email'                 => $data['email'],
            'username'              => $data['username'],
            'password'              => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        
    }

    //This code is used to disable auto-login after registration
    //It overrides the reister function

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

My Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'surname',
        'middle_name',
        'first_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: For validation, create a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation), do not create a method `validation`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti, well noted.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I am not so used to files, so I cannot help you, sorry !